# ACF remove_filter not working for wysiwyg field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

Using ACF and have a field that requires use of wysiwyg field.

I'm trying to apply a filter to the content using `add_filter('acf_the_content')`, but it's not working.

The next thing I tried was to use `remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop')` but this does nothing as well.

Any help or point in the right direction would be swell!

Comment: Where are you adding the add_filter? In functions.php?

Comment: @dafoxuk tried both in `functions.php` and within `single.php` neither work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of how to use the acf_content filter. I can confirm this is working using Twenty Seventeen theme and placing the filter in the theme's functions.php.

`add_filter('acf_the_content', function($content){
    // do some magic to $content
    // e.g. $content = strtoupper($content);
    return $content;
}, 10, 1);`

Hope this helps!